# Are new discoveries in quantum physics (e.g. Amplituhedron) supporting one of the classical QM interpretations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, higgs, amplituhedron

Are new discoveries in quantum physics (e.g. Amplituhedron, Higgs boson) supporting one of the classical QM interpretations? For example Copenhagen, Everett many worlds or Penrose interpretations. Or are these discoveries making new path for new interpretation/theory?

Comment: As far as I know, the only direction in which recent experiments push interpretations of quantum mechanics theory is that we now understand that wave function collapse is not all-or-nothing, and that collapse occurs over a finite amount of time.

Comment: @DanielSank in what sense? Certainly decoherence takes time, but the actual selection of one option out of the decohered possibilities is not usually considered a dynamical process.

Comment: @Radek : can you tell me more about this amplituhedron? Was that discovered at the LHC?

Comment: @RobertMastragostino I made a critical blunder in my comment. You're absolutely right. Established theory has a pure state turning into a mixed one (classical probability distribution) through interaction with other degrees of freedom. That's not the same thing as the observing human seeing realization of *one* of the possibilities in that distribution. That part is what I, personally, would call "the measurement problem" since it is very strange and somehow bizarrely inconsistent with the rest of the theory.

Comment: @JohnDuffield Yes I mean amplituhedron discovered in LHC. The question is if this or another discovery suggested what qm interpretation is right.

Comment: @Radek : you don't happen to know the mass of this amplituhedron do you?

Comment: @JohnDuffield It should be geometric object so I think ot has no mass. Look here https://www.quantamagazine.org/20130917-a-jewel-at-the-heart-of-quantum-physics/

Comment: @Radek the amplitudohedron has very little to do with the experiments at LHC. It's a theoretical construction that allows one to do scattering calculations in a very simple toy model, but has not yet been applied in "realized" theories such as the Standard Model, let alone being tested experimentally.